# How to use scipy.brentq function, to make it equivalent to pascal code?

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

I'm  trying to do some software archaeology. Trying to replace old pascal file with a modern script in python.

At some point, the pascal script is using a routine that looks like this:

```
FUNCTION zbrent(x1,x2,tol: real;fx:Func): real;
(* in the range x1 to x2, ZBRENT searches for a zero point of fx(x:real):real
  until a accuracy of tol is reached. fx must change sign in [x1,x2].
  fx must be defined with the far call option on $F+, and not be nested *)
LABEL 99;
CONST
   itmax=100;
   eps=3.0e-8;
VAR
   a,b,c,d,e: real;
   min1,min2,min: real;
   fa,fb,fc,p,q,r: real;
   s,tol1,xm: real;
   iter: integer;
BEGIN
   a := x1;
   b := x2;
   fa := fx(a);
   fb := fx(b);
   IF (fb*fa > 0.0) THEN BEGIN
      GotoXY(EelX,EelY+8);
      writeln('pause in routine ZBRENT');
      write('Root must be bracketed');
      Readln;
      GotoXY(EelX,EelY+8);
      Writeln('                       ');
      Write('                      ');
      Goto 99;
    END;
   fc := fb;
   FOR iter := 1 to itmax DO BEGIN
      IF (fb/abs(fb)*fc > 0.0) THEN BEGIN
         c := a;
         fc := fa;
         d := b-a;
         e := d
      END;
      IF (abs(fc) < abs(fb)) THEN BEGIN
         a := b;
         b := c;
         c := a;
         fa := fb;
         fb := fc;
         fc := fa
      END;
      tol1 := 2.0*eps*abs(b)+0.5*tol;
      xm := 0.5*(c-b);
      IF ((abs(xm) <= tol1) OR (fb = 0.0)) THEN BEGIN
         zbrent := b; GOTO 99 END;
      IF ((abs(e) >= tol1) AND (abs(fa) > abs(fb))) THEN BEGIN
         s := fb/fa;
         IF (a = c)  THEN BEGIN
            p := 2.0*xm*s;
            q := 1.0-s
         END ELSE BEGIN
            q := fa/fc;
            r := fb/fc;
            p := s*(2.0*xm*q*(q-r)-(b-a)*(r-1.0));
            q := (q-1.0)*(r-1.0)*(s-1.0)
         END;
         IF (p > 0.0) THEN  q := -q;
         p := abs(p);
         min1 := 3.0*xm*q-abs(tol1*q);
         min2 := abs(e*q);
         IF (min1 < min2) THEN min := min1 ELSE min := min2;
         IF (2.0*p < min) THEN BEGIN
            e := d;
            d := p/q
         END ELSE BEGIN
            d := xm;
            e := d
         END
      END ELSE BEGIN
         d := xm;
         e := d
      END;
      a := b;
      fa := fb;
      IF (abs(d) > tol1) THEN BEGIN
         b := b+d
      END ELSE BEGIN
         IF (xm > 0) THEN BEGIN
            b := b+abs(tol1)
         END ELSE BEGIN
            b := b-abs(tol1)
         END
      END;
      fb := fx(b)
   END;
   writeln('pause in routine ZBRENT');
   writeln('maximum number of iterations exceeded'); readln;
   zbrent := b;
99:   END;
```

It is described in [this book, on page 285.](https://books.google.nl/books?id=cyQ_pIMYPEUC&pg=PA322&lpg=PA322&dq=zbrent%20routine%20zero%20point%20search&source=bl&ots=i2iIGUMtU3&sig=ACfU3U3KZ1RHXv4pSW4XXkEyeiyFNefMCg&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj-uYHs3NPpAhULsaQKHZiACUoQ6AEwBXoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=zbrent&f=false) It is Van Wijngaarden-Dekker-Brent method.

I want to replace it with just one line in python, preferably using scipy. I see that there is [scipy.optimize.brentq method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html), but there's one massive difference:

- Pascal's zbrent is using only one tolerance input (tol), while python has rtol and xtol. I don't understand what do they mean.

What to do about it? What should I give as xtol and rtol in my python program to make it equivalent to the pascal one? I don't know anything about numerical computations. I'm scared. I'm just a material scientist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tolerance `tol` in the Pascal code applies uniquely to the length of the remaining bracketing interval as absolute tolerance. Its function corresponds to the `xtol` parameter in scipy. You can ignore `rtol` and leave it at its default value. It should make no difference in standard situations.

In general, for large roots and correspondingly large values for the end points of the bracketing interval, the achievable or desired accuracy will be different than if those values were smaller. This can be controlled via appropriately scaled values for `xtol` if the initial interval is narrow enough. However, if the initial interval is, for some reason, `[1e-6,1e6]` then it might be advisable to control the output accuracy mainly via the relative tolerance.

From the documentation of `brentq`

```
xtol : number, optional
rtol : number, optional
    The computed root ``x0`` will satisfy 
        ``np.allclose(x, x0, atol=xtol, rtol=rtol)``, 
    where ``x`` is the exact root. 

    For nice functions, Brent's method will often satisfy the 
    above condition with ``xtol/2`` and ``rtol/2``. [Brent1973]_
```

and from `np.allclose(a, b, rtol=.., atol=..)`

```
The tolerance values are positive, typically very small numbers.  The
relative difference (`rtol` * abs(`b`)) and the absolute difference
`atol` are added together to compare against the absolute difference
between `a` and `b`.
```